# jqGrid: is it possible to selectively make cells editable?

Tags: jqgrid

how can I make one single cell editable out of a not editable column?
my javaScript looks like this:

```
$( '#grid' ).jqGrid({
    // ...
    cellEdit : true,
    colModel : [
        { name : "id", index : "id", editable : false },
        { name : "wbs", index : "wbs", editable : false },
        { name : "value", index : "value", editable : false }
    ],
    loadComplete : function(data) {
        // ... foreach ( cell in data.rows.columns ) ...
        if ( cell.shouldBeEditable ) {
            jQuery('#grid').setCell(cell.row, cell.col, '', 'green', { editable : true });
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

so, after globally setting columns as not editable, I try to set them as editable locally, based on some criteria (to identify them more easily I also paint them green).

Alas, it's not working: cells become green, but when I try to click them they do not become editable.
Inspecting the selected cell with firebug reveals the `edit-cell` class to be correctly applied.
As a last note, it's working if I set columns as editable in the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice workaround to the problem (thanks to Walter for getting me on the right track).

Instead of locking all the cells and selectively unlocking them in a declarative manner (which may lead to long load times), I'm declaring all the cells as editable.
Then I'm attaching a callback to `afterEditCell` option:

```
var $grid = $('#grid');
$grid.jqGrid({
    // ...
    afterEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        if ( shouldNotBeEditable(iRow, iCol) ) {
            $grid.setCell(rowid, cellname, '', 'not-editable-cell');
            $grid.restoreCell(iRow, iCol);
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

This way the cell is immediately reset to its previous value and I ensure that the callback gets called only once per not-to-be-edited cell, since the cell is made into a `not-editable-cell` after the first call.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it in reverse. Make the column editable, but disable the cells that you do not want to be editable. This is a function I wrote to disable cells:

```
// cellName is the name defined in your colModel
function disableGridCell(cellName) {
    var cell = $('[name="' + cellName + '"]');
    cell.css('display', 'none');

    var div = $("<div>")
        .css('width', '100%')
        .css('height', '100%')
        .css('border', '1px solid #000')
        .css('background-color', '#CCC')
        .text('xxxxxxxxxxxx');

    cell.parent().append(div);
}
```

I call *disableGridCell* inside of my *onEditFunc* of my grid's *editRow* function:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', id, keys, onEditFunc);

function onEditFunc(id) {
   if (condition to disable cell) {
      disableGridCell('CellName');
   }
}
```

Comment: Smart.. I guess I could assign `onEditFunc` to jqGrid option `afterEditCell`. Am I right? (I'm going to try anyhow...)

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel:[
{name:'description',index:'description', width:4, sortable: false, editable: true},
{name:'qty',index:'qty', width:1,sortable: false, editable: true},
{name:'cost',index:'cost', width:1, editable: true, sortable: false},
{name:'totalCost',index:'totalCost', width:1, sortable: false}


onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
//here it will allow editing of either qty or cost col for that rowid 
//only if both cols have a numeric value already    
   if(iCol===1 || iCol===2) {
      var rowdata = $("#projectTable").getRowData(rowid);
      var itemCost = parseInt(rowdata['cost']);
      var qty = parseInt(rowdata['qty']);
      if(!$.isNumeric(itemCost) || !$.isNumeric(qty)) {
         $("#projectTable").jqGrid('setColProp','qty',{editable: false});
         $("#projectTable").jqGrid('setColProp','cost',{editable: false});
      } else {
         $("#projectTable").jqGrid('setColProp','qty',{editable: true});
        $("#projectTable").jqGrid('setColProp','cost',{editable: true});
      }
    }
},
```